# Three button main menu trouble

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm having a bit of trouble with my main menu linking to three different activities
maybe you can have a look at my code and tell me what's wrong. The app is crashing when i click the buttons..I can get one button to link but when I add multiple buttons it doesn't like it.

```
package org.iimed.www;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;





    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton mp= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mpe);
        ImageButton mm= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mid);
        ImageButton um= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ued;
        mp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){



                    public void onClick(View v){
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mpe.class));



                    }
        });



            mm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                public void onClick(View v){

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mid.class)); 


                }
            });


            um.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v){

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ued.class));
                }
            });


    }}
```

Comment: Can you post the logCat log with the exception that crashes the app?

Comment: Make sure `Mpe`, `Mid`, and `Ued` are listed as activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I'm an idiot i had a misplaced Intent filter in my manifest, thanks for your patience